# Failed to fetch https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml - Mac OSX

Tags: android, macos, osx-snow-leopard, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to install an android SDK version using SDK Manager. 
I am getting the error:
 Failed to fetch https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml.

I tryied to use http instead of https but it failed too .

I added sdkman.force.http=true to ~/.android/androidtool.cfg but it failed.
I followed this [link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/63a44163a8d07cd9) but got nothing there worked.
I tried to execute the SDK Manager as root but it failed too.

If I browse to the URL of the xml it shows its contents, so it is accessible.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the ADT eclipse plugin solves the problem. Also you can update the SDK Manager to the last version.